# found string at exact location in the file

Tags: c#

I need to know is there some string at exact location on the .txt file.
I know how to found concrete string with Contains method, but since I do not need to search whole file (string will always be on the same location) I'm trying to find quickest solution.

```
if (searchedText.Contains(item))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Found {0}",item);
   break;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have all the lines loaded in memory ? something like `File.ReadAllLines` ? or do you want to access the specific storage location ?

Comment: Same location in bytes, or in characters? There's a big difference - it's easy to seek to a specific place in a file in terms of bytes, but unless you're using a fixed-width encoding, it's harder to do so for character locations.

Comment: @JonSkeet same location in characters.

Comment: @user1765862: And what's the encoding of the file? And do you *really* mean same location in characters, or actually in terms of lines? (If you could give an example, it would really help.)

Comment: @user1765862: With UTF-8, you'll have to read the whole file before that point - because "10 characters" could mean 10 bytes or 30 bytes, even within the basic multilingual plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in UTF-8 and isn't guaranteed to be ASCII, then you'll just have to read the relevant number of characters. Something like:

```
 using (var reader = File.OpenText("test.txt"))
 {
     char[] buffer = new char[16 * 1024];
     int charsLeft = location;
     while (charsLeft > 0)
     {
         int charsRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(buffer.Length,
                                                         charsLeft));
         if (charsRead <= 0)
         {
             throw new IOException("Incomplete data"); // Or whatever
         }
         charsLeft -= charsRead;
     }
     string line = reader.ReadLine();
     bool found = line.StartsWith(targetText);
     ...
 }
```

Notes:

- This is inefficient in terms of reading the complete line starting from the target location. That's simpler than looping to make sure the right data is read, but if you have files with *really* long lines, you may want to tweak this.
- This code doesn't cope with characters which aren't in the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane). It would count them as two characters, as they're read as two UTF-16 code units. This is unlikely to affect you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(searchedText.SubString(i, l).Contains(item))
```

where `i` is the starting index and `l`  is the length of the string you're searching for.
Since you're using Contains, you have some margin in `l`.